# Importing multi-skinned fbx

Tags: armature, import, .fbx

Here is the thing:

[image]

I am trying to import an FBX (binary) that was firstly exported from Maya.

The peculiarity is that multiple objects were skinned to the same armature, which works perfectly in Maya but as you can see in the picture doesn't seem to be supported in Blender(?).

Is there a way to solve this?